# New play 2.6 application.conf defaults and best practise when creating actors

Tags: playframework, akka

Where can I find the default application.conf for a play 2.6 project?

I just created a new project after not using play for 1 year, and surprised to see the file is empty.

I tried looking in the source but I don't think I have found it:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework.com/blob/master/conf/application.conf

I was looking for the name of the actorySystem which seems to default to "akka://application".

Is it best practise to create your own actorSystem or use the default one that play uses?

If play goes down, my actor system hierarchy should crash also.
But if mine crashes, I don't want play to go down.
Not sure how it works when integrated into an existing play app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The play default configuration file is [located here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Server-configuration-options).

For having multiple Actor Systems, it depends on your use case but for a regular single JVM based web application, no need for the overhead of having multiple actor systems.

If you want to use the default actor system provided by play, look into the [dependency injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.8/ScalaAkka#The-application-actor-system) mechanism given by play. Examples from the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#Akka-deprecated-methods-removed):

> For Scala:
>
> ```
> class MyComponent @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) {
>
> }
> ```
>
> And for Java:
>
> ```
> public class MyComponent {
>
>     private final ActorSystem system;
>
>     @Inject
>     public MyComponent(ActorSystem system) {
>         this.system = system;
>     } }
> ```

For your fear of having the actor hierarchy crash, first try looking deeper into [supervision](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/supervision.html). This is **NOT** supposed to happen if you separate the risky operations from the rest and use actor supervision to monitor them and respond to failure.

Comment: thanks, but that's just the play default, not the entire config correct?

Comment: No, but if you're looking for a complete configuration knowing that just akka's one is a bit long : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/configuration.html#akka-actor

It would be better to know precisely what you're looking for